# Rails 4 new record from different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am currently working on a rails based application to manage orders. (Rails 4.1.5 and ActiveAdmin)

I have these models:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :estimates
  has_many :orders
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :estimates, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :orders, :allow_destroy => true
end
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :line_items, as: :cartable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items, :allow_destroy => true
end
class Estimate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :line_items, as: :cartable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

What I want to do is to create a new Order based on the Estimate record. The things work if I create a new order and show the edit page with:

```
member_action :confirm, :method => :get do
  old_estimate = Estimate.find(params[:id])
  new_estimate = Order.create(old_estimate.attributes.merge({:id => nil, :created_at =>
    nil,:updated_at => nil}))   
  old_estimate.line_items.each do |li|
    new_estimate.line_items.create(li.attributes.merge({:id => nil, :created_at => nil,   
      :updated_at => nil}))
    end
  redirect_to edit_customer_order_path(new_estimate.customer, new_estimate)
end
```

but I would like to use the "new" action and create the record only after it has been edited and confirmed.

I tried to use

```
redirect_to new_customer_order_path(old_estimate.customer, old_estimate.attributes)
```

and it will render the new form but without any parameters in it.
The params are in the URL but I got an "Unpermitted parameters:" in the log. All the params are permitted under Active Admin(either under other.rb and estimate.rb) as:

```
  permit_params :id, :customer_id, :title, :edd, :total,
            line_items_attributes: [:id, :cartable_id, :cartable_type, :product_type, :source_lang, :dest_lang, :unit_price, :total, :_destroy]
```

Anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: were you able to solve this @paulwang ? I am facing similar dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the new action to set some default value in the form:

```
controller do
  def new
    record = YourActiveRecordModel.new #or find, if you pass id
    record.some_attribute = some_value
    new!
  end
end
```

The corresponding input will be filled.